# Hook to set product weight on save_post

Tags: woocommerce, save, product

Is there a way to set product weight with `save_post` hook?

I've following code, but I don't know how to overwrite weight:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'change_weight' );
function change_weight($post_id) {
    $WC_Product = wc_get_product($post_id);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the [`woocommerce_process_product_meta_$product_type`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/cd05b94ec307c14fb970853041aa000155a2a768/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L315) then you don't have to worry about nonces as you can piggy back on WooCommerce's sanity checks.

```
// This will work in both WC 2.6 and WC 2.7
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 'so_42445796_process_meta' );
function so_42445796_process_meta( $post_id ) {
    $weight = 100;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', $weight );
}
```

WC 2.7 will introduce CRUD methods that abstract how the data is saved. I suspect they will eventually move products and product meta out of default WordPress tables, but I can't know for sure. In 2.7 you can use the [`woocommerce_admin_process_product_object`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/cd05b94ec307c14fb970853041aa000155a2a768/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L307) hook to modify the `$product` object before it is saved.

```
// Coming in WC2.7 you can use the CRUD methods instead
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'so_42445796_process_product_object' );
function so_42445796_process_product_object( $product ) {
    $weight = 100;
    $product->set_weight( $weight );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the weight you need to update the post meta. This can be done like this:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', $weight );
```

$weight in the above code is a variable containing the value you want the weight to be. However the save_post hook is triggered every time any post is saved, so blog posts, pages, products, etc. You will probably want to validate that the post is a product. You can do that like this:

```
if ( get_post_type ( $post_id ) == 'shop_order' ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', $weight );
}
```

Also if you want to get the current weight of the product before you alter it you can do it like this:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
$weight = $product->get_weight();
```