# How to update the weight value in the product data, inside an existing woocommerce products without the use of the SAVE/UPDATE button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

What I am trying to achieve here is to update all the weight values inside the products that already exist based on the criteria in the if statement.
So I am using the following code:

```
function update_product_weight_from_dimensions( $product ) { 
        //$product = wc_get_product();
        $squared_dimensions = $product->get_length() * $product->get_width();
        $synthetic_product = $product->get_attribute('pa_composition');
    if($squared_dimensions <= 2.8 && $synthetic_product == 'steel') {
         $product->set_weight(3);
        }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'update_product_weight_from_dimensions', 10, 1 );
```

If i use a hook like `do_action( 'update_product_weight_from_dimensions', 10, 1  );` , nothing will happen.

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445796/hook-to-set-product-weight-on-save-post/42448276#42448276) in StackOverflow , i am already using the `$product->set_weight();` and the hook `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object`. The function already works as expected but only if I SAVE the product. I want to update the values without needing to run inside all products to hit the SAVE/UPDATE button. If this function could run only once then this would also be closer to what I try to achieve.

Comment: From your question I understand that this is a one-time event? So that only needs to be done once? There are some options, but _the most suitable solution rather depends on the number of products involved?_ given that a multi process (performing multiple actions at the same time) will run into timeout errors after a certain time

Comment: @7uc1f3r It is truly a one-time event for a massive number of products (4,411 in total). I was looking at how to avoid a timeout but I think this might also depend on other criteria that I do not know. Maybe a keepalive method could come in handy here. But i don't know if this is something that can be done from inside the woocommerce/wordpress API call. Or I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the weight of standard WooCommerce products is stored solely inside `wp_postmeta` table with the `_weight` meta key.

**Therefore you should be able to use:**
`update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_weight', $your_value );`

I would also recommend to **clear WC transients** after updating the weights (I am not sure if it is needed though).

Anyway, the `$product->set_weight()` and `$product->save()` approach is really the right thing to do. 4000 products really isn't that much and you can always split these into smaller chunks, if it is a one-time action.

Comment: I did add the update_post_meta and used a variable to capture the $product->set_weight(3); . This did not work, but I think will not because of the use of product->set_weight object. I also added the $product->save() inside and outside of the if statement, deleted transients (just in case), and still the existing products did not get the proper value in the weight field. All criteria were met. Also, I think that the update_post_meta could work only with the woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple hook and not with the woocommerce_admin_process_product_object